# Javascript Web3 get the account balance promise / async trouble

Tags: web3js, javascript

I am having difficulty wrapping my head around how to just get the balance:

```
// Testing:
const address1 = "0xA5...";

var balance1 = web3.eth.getBalance(address1);
console.log(balance1);
balance2 = 0;
balance2 = web3.eth.getBalance(address1, (err, wei) => { balance = web3.utils.fromWei(wei, 'ether'); return balance; });
console.log(balance2);
```

But I only get back "promises":

```
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
```

How do I get back these variable values at the "top level" of my code? Or does everything need to be wrapped in an async function somehow? Quite confused... any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to us await and warpped those inside an async function oder user .then(res => ….)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Testing:
const address1 = "0xA5...";

var balance1 = await web3.eth.getBalance(address1);
console.log(balance1);
var balance2 = await web3.utils.fromWei(await web3.eth.getBalance(address1))
console.log(balance2);
```

since web3 calls are mostly async / return promises.

Edit:
If you're using await in a function, your outer function needs to be declared as async.

```js
const address1 = "0xA5...";

const logBalance = async () => {
    var balance1 = await web3.eth.getBalance(address1);
    console.log(balance1);
};

await logBalance();
```

Or use promises (this runs asynchronously)

```js
web3.eth.getBalance(address1).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I get the following: `var balance1 = await web3.eth.getBalance(address1);
               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: declare your surrounding function as async then. I edited the answer to show how. Alternatively, depending on what you need, you can work with promises.

Comment: Hey thanks for the update. Unfortunately I still get `await logBalance();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. Bear in mind I'm running this code in the top level of my app.js node application server.

Comment: If you're running this in your react project  it makes more sense to go with promises. You don't want your main thread to be waiting on calls. Use a state for the balance: web3.eth.getBalance(address1).then(setBalance).catch(console.error);

Comment: I'm not using React, can I do something similar with just regular Javascript/node?

Comment: Hey I'll accept your answer because it's working 'close enough'. I am using this type of code in my server's `app.get` calls for example, then doing an async function on the clientside, and it seems to work :) This type of control flow is new to me.

Comment: yeah, the answer doesn't have anything to do with react. You'll have to read up on async calls and promises to understand it better.